# How to send a fcm notification using javascript cloud functions in flutter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've created an app to test push notifications in a flutter app.

I am able to send a notification from the firebase messaging console and I can receive it as well in the foreground and background.

Once I've done this, I moved to the next step which is to send it automatically using the firebase cloud messaging service and I've used javascript and I've deployed function and it gets executed without any problem.

But the problem is that I can't receive a notification like this:-

[image]

but when I open my app since I've configured the firebase messaging inside initState(); I can see the notification and data get printed as well but I can't receive it like the photo above.

---

What should I do?

try to have a background handler or a top-level method as firebase messaging plugin's read me file says.

---

About my javascript index.js file:

It sends a notification for all the tokens in the pushTokens collection when a new document added to the posts collection and it does this but the problem is that I've mentioned above.

Index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var notificationMessageData;

exports.fcmTester = functions.firestore.document('posts/{postID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const notificationMessageData = snapshot.data();

    return admin.firestore().collection('pushTokens').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            var tokens = [];

            if (snapshot.empty) {
                console.log('No Devices');
                throw new Error('No Devices');
            } else {
                for (var token of snapshot.docs) {
                    tokens.push(token.data().tokenID);
                }

                var payload = {
                    "notification": {
                        "title": "from" + notificationMessageData.writer,
                        "body": "from" + notificationMessageData.name,
                        "sound": "default"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "sendername": notificationMessageData.writer,
                        "message": notificationMessageData.name
                    }
                }

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your app in background and try sending notification again bcoz flutter firebase messaging plug-in will not create notification if you are using the app while the notification has been sent although you can see its data in but to generate notification you have to do it manually if user is currently using the app.

On the other cases plug-in will create notification like if app is terminated or its in background.